# How to prove that there does not exist a union closed family of $n$ sets with all elements with frequency $(n-1)/2$

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is it possible to prove that there does not exist a finite union closed family $\mathcal{F}$, with size $|\mathcal{F}| = n \gt 1$, $n$ odd, such that $\forall a \in U(\mathcal{F})$, $\mathcal{F}_a = \{S \in \mathcal{F} : a \in S\}$ has the property:

$$|\mathcal{F}_a| = \frac{n-1}{2}?$$

I am asking this mainly to "test" if the above conjecture is easier to prove than the union-closed sets conjecture.
Finding an example of a family with the above property should be difficult (it would disprove the Frankl's conjecture), but how difficult is it to prove that no such family exists?

On the other hand it has been proven by Norton and Sarvate in "A note of the union-closed sets conjecture" that a counterexample to the Frankl's conjecture with $n$ minimal has at least three elements with frequency exactly $(n-1)/2$, so maybe one day someone can come up with a proof that a counterexample with $n$ minimal must have all the elements with frequency $(n-1)/2$ (this is just a speculation with no ground).

Comment: Wouldn't such an example refute the still open Fankl's union-closed sets conjecture?

Comment: @Joel Adler I am not asking for an example of such a family, but trying to figure out if it can be easy enough (easier than the Frankl's conjecture) to show that no such example exists: this would not prove nor disprove the Frankl's union-closed sets conjecture.

Comment: I feel obligated to mention the example $\mathcal{F} = \{F \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,k+1\} : F \ni 1\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$, which has $|\mathcal{F}| = 2^k+1$, $|\mathcal{F}_a| = 2^{k-1}$ for all $a \in \{2,\dots,k+1\}$, and $\mathcal{F}_1 = 2^k$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't understand your point.

Comment: @BillyJoe Just giving an example where $|\mathcal{F}_a| = \frac{n-1}{2}$ for all but one value of $a$.

Comment: @BillyJoe Sorry, I didn't read your question properly!